# ¿Pasar gridview a Crystal report con dataset? asp .net c# webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

Hola tengo un proyecto de webform en asp .net con c#, y en el tengo una consulta sql para mostrar datos de varias muchas tablas en un gridview (no puse la consulta sql completa porque es mucho y es de mi trabajo), y quiero exportar esa tabla a un reporte crystal dando click a un boton.

Pero al ejecutar mi proyecto y dar click en el boton no se muestra ni aparece nada.

Aqui dejo mi codigo:

webform1.aspx

```
    <emptydatatemplate>
        ¡No se encontraron reportes!  
    </emptydatatemplate>                

    <Columns>
         <%--campos...--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="campo1" HeaderText="campo1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="campo1" />
```

webform1.aspx.cs

---asi lleno mi gridview---

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * from tabla where cod='" + Session["Cod_user"] + "', con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid1.Visible = true;
            grid1.DataSource = dt;
            grid1.DataBind();

---boton_click ver reporte--

DsRF ds = new DsRF(); //DsRF es el nombre del dataset
            DataTable dt_RF = new DataTable();
            dt_RF.Columns.Add("columna1", typeof(string));
           ---mas columnas----

//Pasar los datos del grid al dataset (esto nose si esta bien)

```
    for (int fila = 0; fila <grid1.Rows.Count - 1; fila++)
      {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid1.Rows[fila].Cells.Count; col++)
      {
            dt_RF.Rows.Add(grid1.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Text);

     }
    }
```

//mostrar el dataset en el crystalview

```
        ReportDocument oRep = new ReportDocument();
        oRep.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Proyecto/myreporte.rpt"));
        oRep.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRep;
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme

Gracias

Saludos

Comment: ¿por que en vez de crear varias preguntas, no edita o aclara la originalmente hecha, ya ha formulado al menos 3 preguntas iguales?

Comment: Si funciona en windows forms pero no en web forms, tal vez se deba a [databind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w7c2tz18(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A tu clase debes de agregar el using de tu clase DataGridViewRow, porque actualmente no está definida en tu clase actual. Esto se hace en la parte más arriba de tu archivo.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

[DataGridViewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx)